# How to save flutter cache on ci to save time on circleci

Tags: flutter, circleci

I use circleci for my automated builds and tests but I dont find a way to save a folder with all of the dependencies of my flutter project and restore them on each build, each time it needs to download all of the dependencies and rebuild everything.

I was hopping to save dependencies and build cache in CI so my builds there are faster.

- Im using this image [cirrusci/flutter](https://hub.docker.com/r/cirrusci/flutter/)
- Docs on [circleci](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `save_cache` and `restore_cache`. Document is [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/).
About Flutter's cache dependencies. You can take a look about this [orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/tadashi0713/flutter-orb#commands-install_pub)